# Search text within multi-line curly braces

Tags: python, regex

I have a large file with similar text patterns as below.

```
{ device_id: 'do0142', message: '[0,"xyz","something",{}]}

{
  device_id: 'Ampn05',
  message: '[0,"23","something",{"connect":1,"error":"something","info":"xyz","valid":"Unavailable","timestamp":"2020-03-15T04:33:32Z","vendorId":"cycle","country":"anywhere"}]}


{ device_id: 'do0142', message: '[0,"xyz","something",{}]}

{
  device_id: 'do0142',
  message: '[0,"23","something",{"connect":1,"error":"something","info":"xyz","valid":"Unavailable","timestamp":"2020-03-15T04:33:32Z","vendorId":"cycle","country":"anywhere"}]}
```

I want to search for a `device_id` within a curly brace and if a match is found, return the entire content within that curly brace.

ex - If I am searching for device_id = 'do0142', output should be something like this:

```
{ device_id: 'do0142', message: '[0,"xyz","something",{}]}

{ device_id: 'do0142', message: '[0,"xyz","something",{}]}

{
  device_id: 'do0142',
  message: '[0,"23","something",{"connect":1,"error":"something","info":"xyz","valid":"Unavailable","timestamp":"2020-03-15T04:33:32Z","vendorId":"cycle","country":"anywhere"}]}
```

I tried with regular expressions in Python, but I am getting only a partial output:

```py
import re

file_name = "log.txt"
word = "do0142"
regex = r"(\[.*\])"

with open("log.txt", 'r', encoding="utf8") as input:
    line = input.read()

matches = re.finditer(regex, line, re.MULTILINE)

for match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        print ("{group}".format(group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Please help me with this Python code.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm pretty sure it can't be done. Handling arbitrary levels of nesting, or a string that contains a curly brace is a bit beyond what regexes are going to do for you. You pretty much need at least a real tokenizer, and a (minimal) parser.

Comment: is there any other way apart from using regex? @JerryCoffin

Comment: If you're not dealing with arbitrary levels of nesting, and you know your blocks of data will always be separated by double spaces, as they do in the example provided, you could do something like this https://regex101.com/r/6IVH28/1

Comment: @PrashantMani: There are lots of parser libraries (and parser generators) for Python. I've used one call `Ply`, but haven't use others enough to recommend it as better than the others.

Comment: Is this a well known file format? There may already be a parser. It looks like this is intended for machine consumption so _something_ knows how to parse it.

Comment: @CAustin thank you for the regex expression, this works for my desired output.

Comment: If you don't provide a consistent test string that illustrates how looks this syntax, don't hope to obtain reliable answers.

Answer (score 0):

A *naïve* approach would be to turn on the [`dot-matches-all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.S) and capture the relevant blocks :

```
with open("log.txt", encoding="utf8") as f:
    key = re.escape("do0142")
    pat = "({\s*device_id:\s*'%s'.+?\s*}$)" % key
    matches = re.findall(pat, f.read(), flags=re.M|re.S)
```

> Demo : [[*regex101*](https://regex101.com/r/nU6juy/1)]

Output :

```
# print(*matches, sep="\n"*2)
    
{ device_id: 'do0142', message: '[0,"xyz","something",{}]}

{ device_id: 'do0142', message: '[0,"xyz","something",{}]}

{
  device_id: 'do0142',
  message: '[0,"23","something",{"connect":1,"error":"something","info":...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reliably parse structured data with regex. Instead, since the format of your input file is apparently multiple YAML documents separated by one or more blank lines, you can use a YAML parser such as [`pyyaml`](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) to parse each group of non-blank lines into a dict, which you can test if it has the `device_id` value you're looking for, in which case the document would make it to the output:

```
import yaml
from itertools import groupby

with open('log.txt') as file:
    for has_content, lines in groupby(file, '\n'.__ne__):
        if has_content:
            data = yaml.safe_load(block := ''.join(lines))
            if data['device_id'] == 'do0142':
                print(block)
```

so that given the following as the input content:

```
{ device_id: 'do0142', message: '[0,"xyz","something",{}]'}

{
  device_id: 'Ampn05',
  message: '[0,"23","something",{"connect":1,"error":"something","info":"xyz","valid":"Unavailable","timestamp":"2020-03-15T04:33:32Z","vendorId":"cycle","country":"anywhere"}]'}


{ device_id: 'do0142', message: '[0,"xyz","something",{}]'}

{
  device_id: 'do0142',
  message: '[0,"23","something",{"connect":1,"error":"something","info":"xyz","valid":"Unavailable","timestamp":"2020-03-15T04:33:32Z","vendorId":"cycle","country":"anywhere"}]'}
```

The code would output:

```
{ device_id: 'do0142', message: '[0,"xyz","something",{}]'}

{ device_id: 'do0142', message: '[0,"xyz","something",{}]'}

{
  device_id: 'do0142',
  message: '[0,"23","something",{"connect":1,"error":"something","info":"xyz","valid":"Unavailable","timestamp":"2020-03-15T04:33:32Z","vendorId":"cycle","country":"anywhere"}]'}
```

Note that I have fixed the unterminated quoted strings in all `message`s in your sample input, which presumably are malformed because of your effort to minimize the input for the question.

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/ImpracticalGreatInsurance